# SharePoint 2010 Infopath query

Tags: infopath, service-application

I need to install Infopath 2010 in SharePoint 2010 server ?

Please share the download link and steps for installation and other key points

Answer (score 0):

Infopath is an office component not a Sharepoint component, there is nothing to install.  Are you referring to Infopath Forms Services? That is tied to the Sharepoint SKU you are using.

Comment: Thanksi guess sharepoint infopath 2010 is  one of the Microsoft office feature like word ,excel am i right ?

please guide me?

i guess just install ms office 2010

Please answer : which version latest for ms office 2010 ??? , recommened MSoffice package version for SharePoint 2010 infopath

Comment: Hi PirateEric Can you help on this ?

Comment: Office 2010 professional should be what you need.

Comment: i need to install infopath 2010 in sharepoint server..

Comment: You don't install infopath in sharepoint. Infopath is part of the office suite. Infopath forms services is a service to configure in central administration if you are running the enterprise version of sharepoint server.

Comment: Ok..Thanks for ur input..So just run the MSOffice professional plus 2010 exe(during the installation just enable the InfoPath feature only)..then its available in Run-->All programes-->Microsoft office-->InfoPath Designer 2010 and InfoPath Filler 2010...

Comment: Ok..Thanks for ur input..So just run the MSOffice professional plus 2010 exe(during the installation just enable the InfoPath feature only)..then its available in Run-->All programes-->Microsoft office-->InfoPath Designer 2010 and InfoPath Filler 2010... we received request Install infopath 2010 in sharepoint server thats all.Note :  InfoPath Forms Services is available in CA  already under General Application settings......So they asked only install the  infopath i mean, msoffice am i correct ?